# strpos function not working from $_post

Tags: php

I have been trying to see if a number is negative or positive and mark it as a fee or commission. The following code is what I have so far,

```
$commm = $_POST['com_fee'];
$findme = '-';
$pos = strpos($commm, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    $comfee = 'Fee';
}
else {
    $comfee = 'Commission';
}
```

For some reason, `$comfee` is always being defined as "Fee". Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A number is negative if less than zero.

Comment: This doesn't seem replicable.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($pos, $comm, $findme, $_POST);` before the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if $_POST['com_fee'] exist, is number and if is >= 0

```
//$commm = $_POST['com_fee'];
$commm_list = [ '', 
    'kjhgfd', 
    'jhgf-dcfvgb', 
    '-', 
    '-1',
    '0',
    '+1',

    ];

function from_stf( $commm ) {

    $findme   = '-';
    $pos = strpos($commm, $findme);

    if ($pos === false) {
      $comfee= 'Fee';
    } else{$comfee='Commission';}

    return $comfee;
}


foreach ($commm_list as $commm) {
    $res = from_stf( $commm );

    print $commm.'  -->  '.$res."\n";
}
```

and results:

```
$ php ./wiksphp/new.php
  -->  Fee
kjhgfd  -->  Fee
jhgf-dcfvgb  -->  Commission
-  -->  Commission
-1  -->  Commission
0  -->  Fee
+1  -->  Fee
$
```

Comment: I had a mistake in the post data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for the '-' symbol can't you just check if the number is negative?

```
$comm = $_POST['com_fee'];

$comfee = $comm < 0 ? 'Commission' : 'Fee';
```